# OAuth using dotnet core and mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm new to mongo DB and for most documentation I am referring to the official [guides](https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/)

At this point I has been able to connect my Web Api solution using dotnet core to the mongo Cloud. Using postman I can fetch, insert, delete some collections. So far so good.

Now, the next steps I would like to do is to implement a login page and store the user information on mongo. But I am not sure the are some best practices, frameworks, or any other helpful information on how to achieve that using mongo with Web Api dotnet core. Will OAuth be a good fit for this? Sorry if this is a silly question just trying to connect the dots.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 0Auth would be overkill unless your app deals with super sensitive data such as banking/financial etc. simple jwt token auth should be sufficient for most apps. i think you might benefit from this [mongo web api starter template](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoWebApiStarter) i've created.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ, thanks for sharing it, I will definitively take a look at it. Probably the only question I have is, For these commands: dotnet new -i MongoWebApiStarter and
  dotnet new mongowebapi -n MyAwesomeApp will be any previous steps that needs to be done? Or directly executing it from the solution folder?

Comment: yeah the only requirement is that you have .net core 3.1 installed on your machine. just open up a command/powershell window and run those commands. it will first install the template and then scaffold a new app using the template. then open up the solution using your favorite ide and explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it working, so closing this thread.

I started taking a look at the proposed link [mongo web api started template](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoWebApiStarter) but ended up with this one [ASP.NET Core 3.1 - JWT Authentication Tutorial with Example API](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api). the last one was talking about more on what I exactly looking for. But I would say both are great resources.